# How to create a Tor-only network interface suitable for Firejail?

Tags: linux, security, privacy, tor, firejail

The well-known but **unsafe** method is to use `torify`. It is unsafe because we *ask* an application to use Tor, not force it. If the application misbehaves or is being exploided by a bug,
it will still allow non-Tor connections to be made to the outside world.

Firejail, on the other hand, is a security tool that allows you to *sandbox*
applications by providing them an isolated kernel namespace,
seccomp filters and, what's important, an custom network stack.

So, **how do I create a Tor-only network interface that could be fed to Firejail**?
According to Firejail documentation, it accepts any bridge network interface:

> Firejail can attach a new TCP/IP networking stack to the sandbox. The new stack comes with its own routing table, firewall and set of interfaces. It is totally independent of the host network stack.
>
> - Create new interfaces – Linux kernel macvlan and bridge devices are created and moved automatically in the sandbox.
> - Move existing interfaces – existing interfaces can be moved inside the sandbox. The interface configuration is preserved.

Answer (score 4):

Firejail with Tor HOWTO
https://www.void.gr/kargig/blog/2016/12/12/firejail-with-tor-howto/

I cannot verify that tor will work as outlined in the above article, however ssh forwarding using the same approach (i.e., a socks5 port) works fine.

Comment: 'redirect traffic from bridge to http proxy' https://superuser.com/questions/1172607/redirect-traffic-from-bridge-to-http-proxy - I am currently using this configuration but with privoxy instead of tinyproxy, which will (as well as ad blocking) route HTTP requests through a SOCKS proxy.

Answer (score 3):

we've implemented another solution as firejail support --netns flag.
in order to bind firejail inside a network namespace that could reach internet via tor only, the steps are:

```
# configure tor with this configuration
AutomapHostsOnResolve 1
TransPort 9040
TransListenAddress 10.0.0.1
DNSPort 5354
DNSListenAddress 10.0.0.1
SOCKSPort 0
```

then..

```
# create a new network namespace named torjail
ip netns add torjail

# create two virtual ethernet  interface
ip link add out-torjail type veth peer name in-torjail

# bind one interface to torjail network namespace
ip link set in-torjail netns torjail

# set interfaces ip and default routing
ip addr add 10.0.0.1/24 dev out-torjail
ip link set out-torjail up
ip netns exec torjail ip addr add 10.0.0.2/24 dev in-torjail
ip netns exec torjail ip link set in-torjail up
ip netns exec torjail ip route add default via 10.0.0.1

# forward all dns traffic to tor DNSPort
iptables -t nat -A  PREROUTING -i out-torjail -p udp -d 10.0.0.1 --dport 53 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.0.0.1:5354

# forward all traffic to tor TransPort
iptables -t nat -A  PREROUTING -i out-torjail -p tcp --syn -j DNAT --to-destination 10.0.0.1:9040

# accept established connection
iptables -A OUTPUT -m state -o out-torjail --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT

# accept only forwarded traffic
iptables -A INPUT -i out-torjail -p udp --destination 10.0.0.1 --dport 5354 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -i out-torjail -p tcp --destination 10.0.0.1 --dport 9040 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -i out-torjail -p udp --destination 10.0.0.1 --dport 9040 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -i out-torjail -j DROP


# finally run firejail within torjail namespace
firejail --dns=10.0.0.1 --netns=torjail $YOUR_ANONYMOUS_COMMAND_HERE
```

we've implemented this method in `torjail` for a simple usage, take a look:

https://torjail.github.io
https://github.com/torjail/torjail