# redirect traffic from bridge to http proxy

Tags: linux, networking, openvpn, sandbox, firejail

If I create a new instance of an ethernet bridge:

```
# brctl addbr br1
# ip link set dev br1 up
# ip addr add 10.100.100.1/24 dev br1
```

Start `tinyproxy` listening on `localhost` on its default port 8888:

```
# tinyproxy
```

With `firejail` create a new network namespace and connect it to the bridge:

```
# firejail --net=br1 /bin/bash
```

How would I then route traffic through the bridge to `tinyproxy`, so that, e.g., `curl` will fetch a Web page from within the `firejail` sandbox:

```
# curl --proxy http://10.100.100.1:8888 http://wtfismyip.com/text
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following command is useful to flush/delete chains and disable `ufw`:

```
# /lib/ufw/ufw-init flush-all
```

Create an ethernet bridge:

```
ext_if="enp8s8"
bridge="brtp8888"
proxy_port="8888"  # tinyproxy default

brctl addbr "${bridge}"
ip link set dev "${bridge}" up
ip addr add 10.100.100.1/24 dev "${bridge}"
# Allow the bridge to route traffic to localhost
sysctl net.ipv4.conf."${bridge}".route_localnet=1
```

Route tcp traffic directed at port 8888 of the bridge through to `tinyproxy`:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i "${bridge}" -p tcp -j DNAT --to-destination 127.0.0.1:"${proxy_port}"
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.100.100.0/24 -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
```

(N.B. The above was adapted from [Firejail with Tor HOWTO](https://www.void.gr/kargig/blog/2016/12/12/firejail-with-tor-howto/).)

Tinyproxy restricts connections to `localhost` unless there is a configuration line otherwise, edit `/etc/tinyproxy.conf`:

```
Allow 10.100.100.0/24
```

A more complete set of iptables rules:

```
iptables -P INPUT DROP
iptables -P FORWARD DROP
iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT

iptables -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -m state --state INVALID -j DROP
iptables -A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT

iptables -A INPUT -i "${bridge}" -p tcp --dport "${proxy_port}" -j ACCEPT
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i "${bridge}" -p tcp -j DNAT --to-destination 127.0.0.1:"${proxy_port}"  # tinyproxy default
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.100.100.0/24 -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
```

The `ufw` equivalent:

```
## Copy the following into /etc/ufw/before.rules (see man ufw-framework, 'Port Redirections')
# *nat
# :PREROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
# -A PREROUTING -p tcp -i brtp8888 --dport 8888 -j DNAT \
#   --to-destination 127.0.0.1:8888
# COMMIT
# *nat
# :POSTROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
# -A POSTROUTING -s 10.100.100.0/24 -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
# COMMIT

ufw allow in on "${bridge}" from 10.100.100.0/24 proto tcp
```

See also this post [Firejail and connecting to the Internet through an host OpenVPN client](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/336070/firejail-and-connecting-to-the-internet-through-an-host-openvpn-client).

If someone can explain why creating a bridge as outlined above, opening a sandbox running firefox with `--net=br1` and setting Firefox's HTTP Proxy to the gateway IP (i.e., `br1`, any port) also works I'd be interested to know.